# `override` overrides nothing, but no error is given

Tags: scala

Here's the example:

```
class A {
  def postStop() {
    println("A.postStop")
  }
}

class B extends A with C {
  override def postStop() {
    println("B.postStop")
  }
}

trait C { this: B =>
  override def postStop() { // here I expected a warning
    println("C.postStop")
  }
}

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    new A().postStop()
  }
}
```

This code prints `B.postStop`, and `C.postStop` override is silently ignored. Why is no warning printed? Is that a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case it's not possible to issue a warning, because the compiler can't be sure that `C.postStop()` is never invoked. There can be another class defined somewhere, that extends `B` and `C` and explicitly calls `C.postStop()`:

```
class D extends B with C {
  override def postStop() {
    super[C].postStop()
  }
}
```

And this will invoke `C.postStop()` when you use it:

```
scala> D().postStop()
C.postStop
```